# Behavior of log axis

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, logarithm, yaxis

I heard Log values should always be a power of log base. I was playing with the log axis demo in highcharts
http://jsfiddle.net/jjg4z79x/

I set `min` value of **yaxis** to 9. This shows unexpected values in labels of log axis 4, 10, 20, 40, 100, 200, 400, 1K

**Expected labels:** 10, 100, ...

**Explanation:**
Minimum value of yaxis scale is 9. But label and ticks should be shown at the next **integer power of logarithmic base**. That is, 10. Similarly, all the other labels should be an integer power of logarithmic base. That is `10 power 1, 10 power 2`, etc..,

Is this the correct behavior of logarithmic axis ?

Comment: Can you explain why do you expect the labels to be 1, 10,100 if you set min to 9?

Comment: it should be 10, 100, 1000, etc. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

You might confuse axis scale with labels displaying.

In fact, you can set the labels to be displayed in whatever value you want ( but greater than 0) with [tickPositions/tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositions). Logarithmic axis means that the scale in a chart is logarithmic but it does not determine how labels are displayed.

```
 yAxis: {
  type: 'logarithmic',
  min: 9,
  startOnTick: false,
  endOnTick: false,
  tickPositions: [Math.log10(10), Math.log10(20), Math.log10(32), Math.log10(40)]
},
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/gu3ogj13/